# Maintain login state om chrome packed app

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am creating chrome app, I would like my users to login or create a user when they first enter the application.

**The goal:**

Maintaining login state on chrome packed app.

**The problem:**

*Cookies -* Chrome packed app have no cookie API, meaning that "document.domain" exists,
But you can't set cookies, at least not using http request.

*Extension-* There is not access to browser extensions (for a non-sandbox pages)

Couldn't think on other solution, Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the session id in the application storage via **chrome.storage.local.set** **chrome.storage.local.get** methods.